# Refresh a tab and not the ReactJs Ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am currently experiencing a problem. I use ReactJs and Ajax but the problem is that on the same page I have 4 tabs. Each tab is a page.
To summarize I have a page that matters 4.
Except that in one of its tabs I have to delete a credit card so once I select the card and I click on the delete button I want it refreshes that my tab but he raffrachi the main page and my tab n ' is more open. So I thought about putting a location.reload () but it refreshed the whole page and does not solve my problem because the active tab closes. 
I give you the code and some pictures for understanding.

Before refresh:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDi70.png)

After refresh:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeA39.png)

While I want it refreshes only tab "means of payment" here is my code:

```
handleCardDelete = () => {
var numCard = $('input[name=rbCard]:checked').val();
console.log(this.state.token);
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://API.....,

    dataType: 'json',

    type: 'DELETE',

    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
    },

    complete: function(){
        alert("carte supprimée avec succès");
        window.location.reload();
    },

});
```

};

My ReactJs Tab:

```
<Button animated='fade' onClick={this.handleAddCardSubmit}>
        <Button.Content visible>
            Ajouter une carte
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Content hidden>
            <Icon name='add' />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>

    <Button animated='fade' onClick={this.handleCardDelete}>
        <Button.Content visible>
            Supprimer la carte
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Content hidden>
            <Icon name='delete' />
        </Button.Content>
```

My ReactJs "Home" Page:

```js
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
    this.setState({activeItem: name});
    if(name === 'Profil'){
      this.setState({fluxActif: <MonProfil/>});
    }
    if(name === 'MoyenDePaiement'){
          this.setState({fluxActif: <MoyenDePaiement/>});
      }
  };
  componentWillMount(){
    const token = localStorage.token;
    this.setState({token});

  };
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu className="MonCompteMenu">
          <h2>Mon Compte</h2>
        </Menu>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <Menu fluid vertical tabular>
              <Menu.Item  name='Profil' active={this.state.activeItem === 'Profil'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} ><p>Mon Profil</p>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item  name='MoyenDePaiement' active={this.state.activeItem === 'MoyenDePaiement'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} ><p id="MoyenDePaiement">Moyen de paiement</p>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </Grid.Column>

          <Grid.Column stretched width={13}>
            <Segment >
              {this.state.fluxActif}
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I continue my research. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use setState() twice like this!!, and don'y put components in state!
refactor your code like this, maybe will solve your problem

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;
    if(activeItem === name) return;
    this.setState({activeItem: name, });
  };

render() {
   const { activeItem } = this.state
   const ActiveTab = activeItem === 'Profil' ? MonProfil : MoyenDePaiement
   return (
      ......
       <Segment >
          <ActiveTab />
        </Segment>

   )
}
```